# why the right click inside IE browser stops the javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, animation, right-click

I have written a simple javascript animation code. When I right click on the document the javascript animation stops and resumes back only when the context menu closes. This happens only in IE and the animation continues if I do the same in other browsers.

I was wondering is there any work around for this so that the animation continues even when the context menu is open.

I googled and all I was able to find was:

1. Disable right click
2. Create a custom context menu

But could not find the reason as why this is happening only in IE.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening only in IE and also a possible solution for this (if any)?

Edit: I have checked in IE7, IE8 browsers in windows

Comment: You might want to specify what version(s) of IE this occurs in, and on what OS(s).

Comment: Have you tried to play this animation on context menu?

Comment: @Michael: I am not sure what you are asking, but the animation stops when context menu opens. my animation is something that happens on the background similar to this site [http://www.lionite.com/](http://www.lionite.com/). The parallax effect on this site stops when i right click inside or use the keyboard shortcut to pull up the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

There is an event called oncontextmenu. It calls the function you want when right button clicked. E.g:

```html
​<html>
  <head></head>
  <body oncontextmenu="document.write('hello');">
  </body>
</html​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​>​​​​​​
```

Just try to call the function to run the animation twice - once on page start, then via oncontextmenu.

**UPDATE**

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VLCsj/16/)! The script here prevents from the original right-click menu to appear during the animation. That is as far as I could get...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am trying to understand whether we are in same page. So I have created a sample of my code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLCsj/4/). Please right click inside the result window when the circle is animating and you can see that animation pauses and resume only when context menu is closed.

Comment: Did you try to execute the function only as oncontextmenu event?

Comment: Yes please see my code in the following link: [http://jsfiddle.net/VLCsj/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/VLCsj/4/)

Comment: @user1386170 Please, pay attention. The function is not executed, because jQuery library is not attached. You'd attached raphael instead. Therefore, you must call elements by the standard way.

Comment: Sorry about that, i forgot to update the link please use this link - [http://jsfiddle.net/VLCsj/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/VLCsj/11/). I want the animation to continue on the background even when the context menu is open. I do not want the animation to start from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah... There are couple of logic dead ends in the script, but anyway, I guess the problem is with IE. Maybe you should try to block the menu while `interval > -1`?

Comment: Thanks, but i do not want to disable the right click and was wondering whether there is a workaround for this issue.